# How to bind to MvxRecyclerView ItemsSource via code?

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, mvvmcross

I am using a MvxRecyclerView in my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/Headline"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
  android:text="My Headline" />
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/Headline"
  android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the fragment code:

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.Main_ViewPager)]
[Register("my.app.fragments.MyFragment")]
public class MyFragment : BaseFragment<MyViewModel>
{
    private MvxRecyclerView recyclerView;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragment, null);

        this.recyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.RecyclerView);
        this.recyclerView.ItemTemplateId = Resource.Layout.MyCell;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyFragment, MyViewModel>();
        set.Bind(this.recyclerView).For(x => x.ItemsSource).To(x => x.Items);
        set.Apply();

        return view;
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    ....

    private ObservableCollection<T> items;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items
    {
        get { return this.items; }
        set
        {
            this.items = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Items);
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

The problem is, that the MvxRecyclerView does not display any data.
But it does, when I define ItemTemplateId and Binding in axml (e.g. local:MvxItemTemplate="...", local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items").

My goal is not to define it in axml.. I want to take the advantages of using these properties in code (e.g. renaming or refactoring issues).

Is it possible to define these bindings in Code?

Comment: Could you share the ViewModel? The code in your Fragment seems to be correct. Maybe you're not using an ObservableCollection<T>?

Comment: I edited the question and added the interesting part of MyViewModel. It is an ObservableCollection<T> - on iOS binding works great with this ViewModel.

Comment: Are there any warnings given in the output?

Comment: No, nothing belonging to Mvx

Comment: Hmhm maybe try it like that:
this.CreateBinding(recyclerview).For("ItemsSource").To<ViewModel>(vm => vm.Items).Apply();

Comment: Also same result - binding doesn't work

Comment: Did you try this just with a Textview and binding a text to it? Could be related to the MvxItemTemplate then, though i never binded that yet in code.

Comment: Nice advice. :)

Set MvxItemTemplate in xml and create the Items-binding in the fragment - and it works :)

How to deal with the binding inside my "cell"? Is it only bindable in xml?

Comment: Did you find if the "cell" can be bound in code?

Comment: Yes. Just use DelayBind() in  your custom ViewHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set MvxItemTemplate in xml and create the Items-binding in the fragment.